# Convert a binary string (SecureRandom.random_bytes) into a hexadecimal string?

Tags: ruby, encryption, binary, hex

I'm [generating](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-random_bytes) a 32 byte key and 16 byte iv for my AES-256 CBC [Ruby encryption implementation](https://rocketjob.github.io/symmetric-encryption/api.html):

```ruby
key         = SecureRandom.random_bytes(32)      # => "m\xD4\x90\x85\xF9\xCD\x13\x98\xAB\v\xBB\xCD\x0E\x17\xFAA\xF9\x99\xAF\e\x8A\xB5\x8Ate\x93[m\x9As\xC7\xCB"
iv          = SecureRandom.random_bytes(16)      # => "\xDF\x95[\xD5\xDD(\x0F\xB8SE\xFCZr\xF1\xB1W"
ruby_cipher = SymmetricEncryption::Cipher.new(
  key: key,
  iv: iv,
  cipher_name: 'aes-256-cbc'
)
ruby_cipher.encrypt("Hello!")                    # => 'qAnTLy7jyiLRkUqBnME8sw=='
```

Question:

How do I convert the key and iv to a hexadecimal string, so I can transport them to the other applications?

Context:

In another application, that uses Javascript [via CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/wikis/QuickStartGuide_v3beta.wiki) I need to receive the key and iv and convert them back to bytes like this:

```js
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    "Hello!",
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key),
    { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv) }
).toString()                                     // 'qAnTLy7jyiLRkUqBnME8sw=='
```

In a third PHP application I will use the Hex strings directly like this:

```php
<?php
openssl_encrypt(
  'Hello!', 'aes-256-cbc',
  key,
  0,
  iv
);                                               // => 'qAnTLy7jyiLRkUqBnME8sw=='
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the job:

```
key = SecureRandom.random_bytes(32)
key_as_str = key.each_byte.map{ |byte| '%02x' % byte }.join
```

I did verify this solution with the following scripts:

`test.rb`

```
require 'securerandom'
require 'symmetric-encryption'

key         = SecureRandom.random_bytes(32) 
iv          = SecureRandom.random_bytes(16)
ruby_cipher = SymmetricEncryption::Cipher.new(
  key: key,
  iv: iv,
  cipher_name: 'aes-256-cbc'
)
hex_key = key.each_byte.map{ |byte| '%02x' % byte }.join 
hex_iv =  iv.each_byte.map{ |byte| '%02x' % byte }.join 
encoded = ruby_cipher.encrypt("Hello!") 

puts "Ruby encoded: #{encoded}"

system("php test.php #{hex_key} #{hex_iv}")
```

`test.php`

```
<?php
$encoded = openssl_encrypt(
  'Hello!', 'aes-256-cbc',
  hex2bin($argv[1]), 
  0,
  hex2bin($argv[2]) 
); 

print "php  encoded: $encoded\n";
```

looks the same on my machine.

Comment: Are you sure this generates a correct Hex string? When trying to insert Hex converted string into my Javascript implementation I get a different encryption result. I've also trid to encrypt a string in Ruby, then tried to decrypt it in Javascript, but without success.

Comment: You'r right. My first code did not add a 0 for small numbers. For instance 10 was simply converted to `a` instead of  `0a`. I did enhance my example.

Comment: Hm strange, I'm still getting different results for my Ruby and JS implementations. But are you sure the conversion itself is correct? Then maybe my problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Within js did you use `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse` ?  You'r example uses `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse`.  I think for php you have to use `key = hex2bin('....')`

Comment: You are right, that was the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the same way `SecureRandom` does for their [#hex](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5bab1304af25a843728dbcd2f3594913740aecb0/lib/securerandom.rb#L175) method:

```
key = SecureRandom.random_bytes(32)
key_as_hex = key.unpack('H*')[0]
```

(Using a single-quoted string works fine here for this non-interpolated string, and is rubocop friendly.)